# Eclipse Wrapping Options Not Being Set

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclise Kepler.  I went into WIndow-Preferences-Java-Code Style-Formatter. I created a new profile built on the default built-in one.  I clicked Edit, went to "Line Wrapping" tab, and set "maximum line width" to 120, set Apply-OK-Apply-OK.  When I auto-format, I'm still getting line wrapping occurring too early. I even tried setting the width higher and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your profile exist 2 tabs. Line Wrapping and Comments. Set 120 too on "maximum line width for comments"